# creating controls to change the speed/frame rate of a youtube video

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to build a custom video player and have not found any method in the youtube api for altering frame rates or such. Does anyone know where I might find a solution. I am hoping to be able to put the video into a half speed/solw-motion playback.

Comment: I don't think this will ever be possible, unless YouTube implements it themselves, which is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible, but only when using the  Player with HTML5  playback: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_rate